# Print text in one textbox by clicking more than one button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to print text in textbox by clicking buttons i.e., for example,
if i click on button1, in textbox text should be "a"
If i click on button2, textbox text should be "ab" in ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle button's click event.

Try this,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Click += (sa, ev) => { TextBox1.Text = "a"; };
    Button2.Click += (sa, ev) => { TextBox1.Text = "ab"; };
}
```